# Should I use collect or Array to shallow copy an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, copy, julia

I have an array `a` that I need to shallow copy into an array `b`. 
Should I use

```
b = collect(a)
```

or

```
b = Array(a)
```

and which are the differences of using one or the other?

Comment: Possibly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115414/copy-or-clone-a-collection-in-julia

Comment: Yes, it is similar, but do not address the advantages/disadvantages of `copy` wrt `collect` and `Array`, for the specific case of arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`copy`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base.html#Base.copy) is what you're looking for: `b = copy(a)`.

Indeed, you can also use `collect` or `Array` to finish the job, but what's the differences? In Julia, there're many handy helper functions/macros that one can use to dig out what's happening under the hood.

`@which`, `@edit` or `@less` is frequently used for determining which method is called in the source code:

```
julia> a = rand(3,3)
julia> @which collect(a)
collect(itr) at array.jl:273

julia> @which Array(a)
(::Type{T}){T}(arg) at sysimg.jl:53

julia> @less collect(a)
collect(itr) = _collect(1:1 #= Array =#, itr, iteratoreltype(itr), iteratorsize(itr))
...
...

julia> @less Array(a)
(::Type{T}){T}(arg) = convert(T, arg)::T
...
...
```

Here the code tells that `collect` regarded `a`(an array) as an iterator and then did some iterator-manipulating stuff instead of only a shallow copy. I recommend to use Julia's debug package [`Gallium.jl`](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl) if you would like to further dig into the code. `Array(a)` just did a convertion which is better than `collect`, but also not necessary. The code for `copy` is actually very low-level:

```
copy{T<:Array}(a::T) = ccall(:jl_array_copy, Ref{T}, (Any,), a)
```

Another powerful tool is `@code_xxx` macro:

```
julia> @code_
@code_llvm     @code_lowered   @code_native    @code_typed     @code_warntype
```

For example, you can retrieve and compare the LLVM-IR code to observe the differences:

```
julia> @code_llvm Array(a)

define %jl_value_t* @julia_Type_73446(%jl_value_t*, %jl_value_t**, i32) #0 {
top:
  %3 = alloca %jl_value_t**, align 8
  store volatile %jl_value_t** %1, %jl_value_t*** %3, align 8
  %4 = load %jl_value_t*, %jl_value_t** %1, align 8
  ret %jl_value_t* %4
}

julia> @code_llvm copy(a)

define %jl_value_t* @julia_copy_73507(%jl_value_t*) #0 {
top:
  %1 = call %jl_value_t* inttoptr (i64 4478340144 to %jl_value_t* (%jl_value_t*)*)(%jl_value_t* %0)
  ret %jl_value_t* %1
}
```

`@code_llvm collect(a)` will return a bunch of code since it does more than just a simple copy. I'm not familiar with LLVM, so I can't tell much more.

Comment: great! didn't know about the existence of `copy`. Could you please give some hint about the differences between `collect`, `Array` and `copy` when copying an array. It seems the result is the  same. Perhaps, collect is less efficient  because it creates the array iterating instead of copying all the contents at once?

Comment: @eguaio yes, in this case(do a shallow copy), `collect` did more unnecessary jobs to manipulate the iterating stuff.

Comment: If you want to copy into a preexisting array `b`, which the question seems to imply, use `copy!`, not `copy`.

Answer (score 3):

***[copy](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/)*** is the right one!

```
help?> copy
search: copy copy! copysign deepcopy unsafe_copy! cospi complex Complex Complex64 Complex32 Complex128 CompositeException

  copy(x)

  Create a shallow copy of x: the outer structure is copied, but not all internal values. For example, copying an array
  produces a new array with identically-same elements as the original.
```