# Replace the specific element in array also change other one

Tags: julia

Here is the example code. I can't understand why the first element in array B also be revised. Can I keep the same element in array B?

```
julia> A = [0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3];

julia> B = A;

julia> A[1] = 0.1;

julia> A
1×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.1  0.1  0.2  0.3

julia> B
1×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.1  0.1  0.2  0.3
```

Comment: Another possible duplicate, probably a better one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35115414/1233251 `B = A` is a variable assignment, both variables will be bound to the same array. You can use `copy` to create a new array for the variable `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia `Array` is passed by reference. You need to create a copy:

```
julia> A = [0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3];

julia> B = deepcopy(A)
1×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3

julia> A[1] = 0.1;

julia> A, B
([0.1 0.1 0.2 0.3], [0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3])
```

Note that for this code just `copy` will be also enough but if for example you have an Array of objects that you mutate `deepcopy` should be used.